# Combining different meshes, and UV's of a character?

Tags: mesh, uv, baking, unreal-engine

i am new to the site, so please bear with me.

I have created a character for a game (game built in UE4). The character is already rigged and works in the engine, however the character i made is composed of different meshes (arms, legs), each with its own UV map and texture. This is a problem because the game engine treats the entire character as a single mesh, and i can only apply a single texture to the mesh. Is there any way of baking the textures already applied? or is there some other solution to dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tile the individual textures inside one file by using GIMP or similar and scale the UVs in Blender, because they are relative to the image size. If you have only a few meshes, this is done rather quickly.
Baking all textures together will be a problem if the UVs overlap.